# Teach model to analyze array and output array of same size with boolean entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

First let me state that I am new to deep learning and this example can easily be hard coded but I would like to see if I can teach a model this. This problem is purely practice that I have made up for myself. So the problem is this,

I have a matrix representing R[ed] values in an image. The image just contains blobs of different shades of red. Id like to create a model that can output a matrix of the same size as the input with a Boolean for each pixel representing whether it is > than 128 or not. Again, this is very easy to hard code but i wanna teach this to a model. I have lots of images that have different shaped blobs and this is currently what I can do.

I can make the dataset which is an array of shape (500, 100, 100), 500 images that are 100 by 100 which contains R[ed] values between 0 and 255. as well as another array which is the 'answers'. An array of shape (500, 100, 100) which contains True/False for each pixel.

I can make the dataset which is an array of shape (500, 100, 100), 500 images that are 100 by 100 which contains R[ed] values between 0 and 255. as well as another array which is the 'answers'. An array of shape (500, 100, 100) which contains True/False for each pixel. I have the code below as well.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10000, activation=tf.nn.softmax))


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=5) # X and y are the arrays
```

Does not work. Im not sure what to set the value for the last Dense layer because their are true options for each pixel, true or false, but their are 10000 points. Is this approach correct? Or rather than having a model for a whole image, should i just make one for each pixel, then when trying to run it for a whole image i just loop through every pixel? Is their a way that i can make it so that the model itself take in an image and outputs an array like i want it to?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. It's good that you've provided a detailed explanation of the problem you're trying to solve. But it's not quite clear what your question is. A simple "Does not work" does not provide enough information here, please explain a little more what exactly doesn't work in your code and ask a clear question so you can get the answer you're looking for. Also I would modify the title to be a clear and specific question

Comment: okay. i will edit it